# Styling a lot of markers from GeoJSON File with Live Data

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a dynamically created GeoJSON file that contains data with specific lat/long, timestamp and type information. This data is continually updated and needs to be displayed live on to a google map. Here is a snippet:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection","features": [
{"type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point", 
        "coordinates": [149.522, -30.3603]},
        "properties": {
            "id": "20447637",
            "lat": "-30.3603", 
            "long": "149.522", 
            "timestamp": "1450247155", 
            "strokeType": "0", 
            "mag": "19.9"
        }
    },
{"type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point", 
        "coordinates": [149.555, -30.3647]},
        "properties": {
            "id": "20451255",
            "lat": "-30.3647", 
            "long": "149.555", 
            "timestamp": "1450247646", 
            "strokeType": "3", 
            "mag": "0"
        }
    },...
```

I am currently importing this geojson file using an ajax call to a php script that generates the required data from a database, this all works well and is reponsive. The issue is when I try and style these items it can cause the browser to crash (there can be many thousand of these). Here is the code I am currently using to style them:

```
function styleFeature(feature) {
    var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    var timeElapsed = seconds - feature.getProperty('timestamp');
    var fraction = timeElapsed/(TimeScale/255);
    var color = 'rgb(' + Math.round((255 - fraction)) + ', 0, ' + Math.round(0 + fraction) + ')';
    if(timeElapsed<15) { var stkWeight = 2; var stkColor = "#000"; } else { var stkWeight = 0.5; var stkColor = "#fff"; }
    if(feature.getProperty('strokeType')==0) {
        if(feature.getProperty('mag')>0) {
            return {
                icon: {
                    path: 'm5.219986,29.697235l23.795303,0l0,-25.117241l24.409424,0l0,25.117241l23.795288,0l0,25.765518l-23.795288,0l0,25.117264l-24.409424,0l0,-25.117264l-23.795303,0l0,-25.765518z',
                    strokeWeight: stkWeight,
                    strokeColor: stkColor,
                    fillColor: color,
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,
                    scale: 0.12 * scale
                },
            };
        } else {
            return {
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
                    strokeWeight: stkWeight,
                    strokeColor: stkColor,
                    fillColor: color,
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,
                    scale: 1.5 * scale
                },
            };
        }
    } else {
        return {
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                strokeWeight: stkWeight,
                strokeColor: stkColor,
                fillColor: color,
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                scale: 2 * scale
            },
        };
    }
}
```

There are 3 different types of icons, two of them are the default icons from Google while one is a custom + shape. Each feature from the geojson file is styled as follows:

- The colour of the icon is dependant on its timestamp (Red is current while blue is old)
- The 'strokeType' and 'mag' fields determine which icon to use (Circle, Triangle, Plus)
- New icons in the last x seconds are given a thicker black border

This is all called from `map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);` which is directly after `map.data.addGeoJson(geoJSONDataFromAjaxCall);`

This script is then called every x seconds to retrieve updated information and that info then also needs to be plotted on the map with the others. Data that gets older than the predetermined time (say 60 minutes or 3600 seconds old) needs to be removed, and each marker needs to have their colour changed as they get older.

I have been able to achieve all of the above, however when there are more than a few hundred icons in the viewport the browser gets clogged up and can crash. If I use the standard markers without styling them it works fine. I am after a way to style these icons without crashing the browser, I am guessing the way I am doing it is very resource intensive.

Comment: Are you running the styleFeature() function on all of the markers (aka thousands?). Recalculating lines 2-5 of the function on every feature could be taken out of the function and significantly reduce computation/resources.I would break that function into quite a few based on the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Try to call `map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);` before `map.data.addGeoJson()` , otherwise the API needs to loop 2 times over the data

Comment: @TheBrofessor Unfortunately each marker needs to have that calculation done in order to determine it's colour and type. Would it be faster if that calculation was done outside of the styleFeature function? I'm not sure on the quickest way for code to run in Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks for that suggestion however it seems to have had little effect.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior could occur once the amount of objects (e.g. circle marker icons) is reaching 1k or above, the performance would degrade considerably. Usually in that case it is suggested to render objects via canvas tile overlay.

For that purpose lets introduce a [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView) that is intended for *displaying marker icons*

Source: [iconsoverlay.js](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/6dd435ebacd720f0ad10)

**Example**

This is a similar example that demonstrates how to load GeoJSON data and display markers with custom icons:

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -30.3647,
            lng: 149.555
        },
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

   
    
   

    var overlay = new IconsOverlay(map);
    
    //1.load GeoJSON data
    var data = generateData(1000);
    //2.display custom icons
    data.features.forEach(function (f, id) {

        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(f.geometry.coordinates[1], f.geometry.coordinates[0]);

        if (id > 0 && id % 2 == 0) {
            //add circle icon
            var circleIconProperties = {
                id: id,
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                fillColor: 'rgba(160,16,0,0.5)',
                scale: 10
            }
            overlay.addIcon(position, circleIconProperties);
            console.log(id);
        }
        else if (id > 0 && id % 3 == 0) {

            //add path icon
            var pathIconProperties = {
                id: id,
                path: 'm5.219986,29.697235l23.795303,0l0,-25.117241l24.409424,0l0,25.117241l23.795288,0l0,25.765518l-23.795288,0l0,25.117264l-24.409424,0l0,-25.117264l-23.795303,0l0,-25.765518z',
                strokeWeight: 2,
                strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                fillColor: 'rgba(160,16,0,0.5)',
                scale: 0.4
            }
            overlay.addIcon(position,pathIconProperties);
        } else {
            var arrowIconProperties = {
                id: id,
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
                strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                fillColor: 'rgba(160,16,0,0.5)',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                scale: 4
            }
            overlay.addIcon(position, arrowIconProperties);       
        }     
    });
}







//Helper methods

function generateData(count) {
    var data = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": []
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var lat = getRandomArbitrary(-30.0,-15.0);
        var lng = getRandomArbitrary(120.0,150.0);
        
        data.features.push({
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [lng, lat]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": i.toString(),
                "lat": lat.toString(),
                "long": lng.toString(),
            }
        });
    }
    return data;
}





function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/vgrem/6dd435ebacd720f0ad10/raw/4af8287e17c3aea92b50681d0a9061f2b620f70d/iconsoverlay.js"></script> 
<div id="map"></div>
```

[**Demo page**](http://embed.plnkr.co/REtgZM3P1FxfwLaiScqo/)

Comment: Thanks for that response, I tried it on the Demo page and it is still very unresponsive?

Comment: @ShaneEkerbicer,  I agree, but still it is much faster then rendering markers using default approach. Maybe in that case you need to consider a different approach for displaying markers called [Grid-based clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers)?

Comment: I just implemented your approach and you are right it is much faster, almost instantaneously displays the markers and can still move around the map without too much lag. I am wondering through, I need to be able to remove all markers and remove only markers who's timestamp exceeds a certain value (ie more than 1800 seconds old) Is this possible with this method or would the entire canvas have to be cleared/redrawn?

Comment: Regrading removing markers, one option to consider would be to manipulate the visibility of DOM (canvas) elements as demonstrated in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/51mjad0j/)